# Xamarin.ios app is crashing in iOS 11

Tags: xamarin.ios

App build in Xamarin 6.3 (Build 864) crashes at one instance. However, it does not crash every time but after some 4-5 scenarios it gets the crashed. And moreover, we are finding the crash report only with iOS 11. In iOS 10 it is working fine.

Please find the logs below:

```
Incident Identifier: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

CrashReporter Key:   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Hardware Model:      iPad4,8

Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.xxxxxxx.xxxx.prod [922]

Date/Time:           2017-09-26 13:29:33.7822 +0530
Launch Time:         2017-09-26 13:27:13.2363 +0530
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.0 (15A372)
Baseband Version:    8.01.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-update watchdog transgression: com.xxxxxxxx.xxx.prod exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds |  | Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 0.780 (user 0.780, system 0.000), 71% CPU | Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.001, 0% CPU | 
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  tid_303  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:

Can anyone help me over here what

Comment: https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-15-3-5-with-xcode-9-support/ Sounds like you are not using the latest Xamarin development toolchain yet. Then issues are expected.

Comment: I am using Xamarin Studio 6.3 and XCode version is 8.3.3. But, it is working fine with iOS 10 however not in iOS 11. Moreover, this crash causes once in 4-5 scenarios not on every attempt.

Comment: Is this your first time to develop a mobile app? Even if you use Objective C or Swift, to develop an iOS 11 compatible app you need to upgrade to Xcode 9. For Xamarin, the same rule applies, that you have to upgrade all bits to the latest.

Comment: So you mean to say should I need to update the XCode to version 9 and Xamarin Studio 6.3 to Visual Studio for MAC latest version? BTW yes, I am newbie on mobile development and even on iOS environment.

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/get-apps-ready-ios-11/